# Spring 3 SimpleMappingExceptionResolver warnLogCategory log4j

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

```
<bean id="exceptionResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <map>
              <entry key="java.lang.Exception" value="error"/>
            </map>
          </property>
<property name="warnLogCategory" value="abcdefg"/>
</bean>
```

I would like to log the exception above into a .log file, but it does not log =(. Could someone comment on what might be wrong with my log4j properties...or anything else?

Using Spring 3.0.5

thanks

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, pqe
log4j.category.abcdefg=WARN, pqe

log4j.appender.pqe=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.pqe.DatePattern=_yyyyMMdd
log4j.appender.pqe.File=D:\\pqe.log
log4j.appender.pqe.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.pqe.layout.ConversionPattern=%d|%5p|%c %m%n
```

Comment: What happen if you simpify your log4j config (onle the root logger). Does the message occures in the std out and is the error view shown?

Comment: Works fine for me. How the exception to be logged is thrown?

Comment: It just prints in console [1/7/11 12:59:31:565 EST] 0000001f abcdefg       W org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver logException Handler execution resulted in exception
                                 java.lang.Exception: some error test

Comment: from my controller, I just did   if(true) {
   throw new Exception("some error test");
  }    I have log4j jar and tried to include/exclude commons logging jar.

Comment: I am using Websphere, what I noticed is that if I just type import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory; on my controller and if I do open delcaration on the class, it points to a jar in  C:/.../SP75/runtimes\based_v61\plugins\com.ibm.ws.runtime_6.1.0.jar

Comment: Maybe it is a WebSphere related problem - I have extended my answer

Answer (score 3):

my solution is override method **logException** in **SimpleMappingExceptionResolver**

new resolver:

```
public class LoggingExceptionResolver extends SimpleMappingExceptionResolver {
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingExceptionResolver.class);

@Override
protected void logException(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
    this.logger.warn(buildLogMessage(ex, request), ex);
}
```

}

spring config:

```
<bean id="exceptionResolver" class="com.zyam.isu.core.utils.log.LoggingExceptionResolver">
    <property name="defaultErrorView">
        <value>error.jsp</value>
    </property>
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.lang.RuntimeException">error.jsp</prop>
            <prop key="java.lang.Exception">error.jsp</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

logback.xml

```
    <logger name="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
    <level value="warn" />
</logger>
```

I think logback config is similar with log4j, hope could help you

Answer (score 2):

Try to extend it with something like:

```
public class LoggingExceptionResolver extends SimpleMappingExceptionResolver {

     public LoggingExceptionResolver(String category) {
         super();
         this.warnLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(category); // or whatever log implementation
     }

}

<bean id="exceptionResolver" class="package.name.LoggingExceptionResolver">
    <constructor-arg value="abcdefg"/>
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <map>
            <entry key="java.lang.Exception" value="error"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But this is basically the same thing as:

```
<!-- whatever the implmentation/class name is -->
<bean id="log" class="org.apache.log4j.logger.Logger" factory-method="getLogger">
    <constructor-arg value="abcdefg"/>
</bean>

<bean id="exceptionResolver" class="package.name.LoggingExceptionResolver">
    <property name="warnLogger" ref="log" />
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <map>
            <entry key="java.lang.Exception" value="error"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

with the correct `log4j.logger.abcdefg=WARN`

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple log4j.jar provided to you application by multiple classloaders and your app is finding the wrong one and using the default configuration from there almost certainly. You can verify this by starting your application with

```shell
java -Dlog4j.configuration=/path/to/log4j.properties ... StartupClass
```

log4j will always use the system property before it searches for another file.

If that fixes your problem you will need to tweak your build to only include the log4j related resources that you really need and remove the system property.