# Spring Transactional DAO, exceptions swallowed

Tags: java, spring, aop, dao

I'm using Hibernate as ORM and I have my DAOs annotated with `@Repository`.

I have configured AOP advice this way.

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="save*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        <tx:method name="edit*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        <tx:method name="*" read-only="true" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

They work fine it's just that if any sql exception happens in these methods they're not caught and hence not printed! I'm guessing because transactions commit after executing the method but I'm not sure.

How do I handle it?

Comment: r u sure you don't have a try/catch somewhere?

Comment: I have Exception Resolver configured in context for a better user experience.
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver which catches all Exceptions and redirects to a certain view. 

I removed it and now it catches and prints HibernateExceptions, good news. But I still want to keep the Exception Resolver, do you have any ideas and yet print exceptions in console?

Thanks for giving me the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626728/spring-3-simplemappingexceptionresolver-warnlogcategory-log4j). It suggests extending SimpleMappingExceptionResolver

```
public class LoggingExceptionResolver extends SimpleMappingExceptionResolver {
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingExceptionResolver.class);

@Override
protected void logException(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
    this.logger.warn(buildLogMessage(ex, request), ex);
}
```